# Android - Disabling Text To Speech Logging for Data Security

Tags: android, text-to-speech

My application has some data which I would like to keep secure. I have also enabled the application to use text-to-speech. Unfortunately, the application writes out whatever it says to the log file. This means that a third party application (with permissions to access the logs) could gain access to the data. Is there any way I can disable Android logging the text to speech data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an issue on the [Android Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10297&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).